# Python: .replace doesn't work in method function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext

When I run this:

```
def Replace(word):
    word.replace('o', 'x')
    return word

print Replace('word')
print 'word'.replace('o', 'x')
```

I get this:

```
word
wxrd
```

I am just starting to use Python but I don't understand how my outputs would be any different. Can anyone clarify? I'm using 2.7.6.

Answer (score 1):

`.replace()` **doesn't replace in place** - it *returns a new string* which you should return:

```
def Replace(word):
    new_word = word.replace('o', 'x')
    return new_word
```

Answer (score 0):

You discard the result of `str.replace()`, and return the original word. Try returning the result instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
def Replace(word):
a = word.replace('o', 'x')
return a

print Replace('word')
print 'word'.replace('o', 'x')
```

Then you should get:

```
wxrd
wxrd
```